# How to limit the file type in HTML upload box?

Tags: html

I look around on the Net but cannot find the solution.
But I just found that when we upload file to Flickr,
the file dialog filter the file types automatically, how to make it??

Comment: Depends on how you handle the uploads, but these are possible dupes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240934/html-file-input-field-with-limited-file-types and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739692/limiting-file-upload-type

Answer (score 4):

you can't get the .value property of a  as mentioned in the other answer. it's restricted for security reasons.

there is also an 'accept' attribute which might be handy, eg:

```
<input type="file" name="picture" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/jpg" />
```

i'm not sure how well supported it is among the various browsers though.

you can however create your own upload components using another technology such as java or flash.

Answer (score 1):

You could parse `.value` property of this input and check for file extension using `substr()` method (i.e. if last 3 letters == 'png' etc.)

To perform more complex check you'd have to do it server-side.

**Edit:**
This is a jQuery code that will do the job for you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Checker = {
        Extensions: ["jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp"],

        Validate: function(objid)
        {
            return jQuery.inArray(objid.value.substr(objid.value.length - 3, 3), Checker.Extensions) > -1;
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submitButton').click(function(){
            if (Checker.Validate($('#selectFile')[0]))
            {
                alert("OK, we can submit!");
            } else {
                alert("This file type is not supported. \n Supported file types are: " 
                + Checker.Extensions.join(", "));
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<input type="file" id="selectFile" />
<input type="button" id="submitButton" value="Submit" />
```

Note: `accept` attribute does not work correctly on major browsers so javascript solution is best here, but please remember to check your file on server side again.